# Python re.findall regex problems

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find some very specific data in a string. The problem is I'm not finding all of the data with the current regex I'm using. Here is some sample data:

```
[img:2gcfa9cc]http&#58;//img823&#46;imageshack&#46;us/img823/3295/pokaijumonlogo&#46;jpg[/img:2gcfa9cc]

Making these little guys into Kaiju monsters.  Again, I know nothing about them, other then which ones I thought would make for cool possible Kaiju (of the original 150) so here's Day 01

[b:2gcfa9cc][size=150:2gcfa9cc]BULBASAUR[/size:2gcfa9cc][/b:2gcfa9cc]
[i:2gcfa9cc]Feb 01[/i:2gcfa9cc]
[ddf2k12:2gcfa9cc]http&#58;//img853&#46;imageshack&#46;us/img853/2185/dailydrawfeb2012day01&#46;jpg[/ddf2k12:2gcfa9cc]

Setting myself up with the same &quot;parameters&quot; as last year

I may be breaking my own Challenge rules right now but...well I started this last night and I couldn't just leave 'em out in the cold all unfinished 'n' shit.  

Obligatory Skyrim drawing.

[ddf2k12:2ytorpmj]http&#58;//4&#46;bp&#46;blogspot&#46;com/-UIUSNXvnHz4/TynYf1BZ9oI/AAAAAAAAAl4/pRLHVP0Ny3U/s1600/01_cheatingcheaterwarmup1&#46;jpg[/ddf2k12:2ytorpmj]
```

What I'm trying to get is the data between the `ddf2k12` tags and the `img` tags. I've only worked on the `ddf2k12` tags thus far (I figure the latter will be the former with img instead of `ddf2k12`) and out of the 1586 tags I should have found, I'm only getting 5. Here's my regex:

```
ddf2k12_regex = '(\[[ddf2k12]+\:[A-Za-z0-9]+\])(.*?)(\[[ddf2k12]+\:[A-Za-z0-9]+\])'
ddf2k12_find = re.findall(ddf2k12_regex, post)
```

Obviously there's something wrong with my regex, but after banging my head against a wall I can't sort it out, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will do yourself a big favor by breaking down that big regex into parts and use composition. This seems to work correctly, and it's more obvious how to debug it.

```
import re

start_tag =    '(\[{tagname}:[^\]]+\])'
end_tag = start_tag.replace('\[', '\[\/', 1)
content = '((?:.|\n)*?)' # The ?: indicates a non-capturing group.                                                                                             
tag = start_tag + content + end_tag

ddf_tag=tag.format(tagname='ddf2k12')

for match in re.findall(ddf_tag, post):
    print match
```

Comment: Much better! I still wonder about dot getting stuck at newlines, though.

Comment: YES! Thanks so much that worked perfectly. And yes making it much more legible was definitely a better move. I prefer to use the %s tag to concatenate strings, but that was the only thing I did differently. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Two things. First, you're missing the `/` in the closing `ddf2k12` tag.

```
>>> ddf2k12_regex = '(\[[ddf2k12]+\:[A-Za-z0-9]+\])(.*?)(\[/[ddf2k12]+\:[A-Za-z0-9]+\])'
>>> re.findall(ddf2k12_regex, post)
[('[ddf2k12:2gcfa9cc]', 'http&#58;//img853&#46;imageshack&#46;us/img853/2185/dailydrawfeb2012day01&#46;jpg', '[/ddf2k12:2gcfa9cc]')]
```

So now it works. But you're putting the `ddf2k12` characters in brackets, which will match any tag with the characters `1`, `2`, `d`, `f` or `k`.

```
>>> silly_s = '[dddd:a]a[/ffff:a]'
>>> re.findall(ddf2k12_regex, silly_s)
[('[dddd:a]', 'a', '[/ffff:a]')]
```

So you need to match the exact tag instead; to do so, remove those outer brackets:

```
>>> ddf2k12_regex = '(\[ddf2k12\:[A-Za-z0-9]+\])(.*?)(\[/ddf2k12\:[A-Za-z0-9]+\])'
>>> re.findall(ddf2k12_regex, post)
[('[ddf2k12:2gcfa9cc]', 'http&#58;//img853&#46;imageshack&#46;us/img853/2185/dailydrawfeb2012day01&#46;jpg', '[/ddf2k12:2gcfa9cc]')]
>>> re.findall(ddf2k12_regex, silly_s)
[]
```

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter in this case, but don't forget to make your regex strings [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) by prepending `r` to them.

Comment: I think I would like to see such a long pattern in a `r'''...'''` string across multiple lines in `(?x)` mode with extra white space with each chunk of it on its own line and maybe with comments too, in order to make it easier to read and maintain. I get a bit claustrophobic when it’s all scrunched together, risking sending the reader into punctuation shock. 

Comment: This did work and thank you for the help. i chose the previous answer due to the fact that they broke it up further, which while it wasn't part of my question, will make it easier to re-use it for the img tag as well. +1'd though.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```
post = "[the data you want to be searched for using regex]"
ddf2k12_regex = re.compile(r"\[ddf2k12(?P<data>[\n.]*?)\[/ddf2k12")
ddf2k12_find = ddf2k12_regex.findall(post)
```

Comment: I found it confusing that you’re using `data` **not only** as the variable name **but also** for the named group as well; wouldn’t it be better to choose different identifiers? Also, I wonder whether you want `(?s)` or `re.DOTALL` in there so that the dot can cross newline boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using character set where you shouldn't. Try the following regex instead:

```
pattern = r'\[ddf2k12:\w+?\](.*?)\[/ddf2k12:\w+?\]'
```

\w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Note that the semantics of \w and of the dot, as in (.*?), can be changed by using the DOTALL, LOCALE and UNICODE flags, or by adding (?s), (?L) or (?u) to the regex.

Comment: Do you think you might want `(?s)` in there so that the dot can cross newline boundaries?  Also, `\w` can include Unicode with `(?u)`, or locale stuff with `(?l)`. I now use the Unicode-flavor almost always, and no longer ever use the locale-flavor of it myself.

Comment: @tchrist: That's a good point. I guess you might want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping text together is `(sometex)`, not `[sometext]`. And I thought that `ddf2k12` tag could appear once in side your `[...]`. Drop `+` off and you'll now no need an `(...)`.

```
\[ddf2k12:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\](.*?)\[/ddf2k12:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]
```

Would do the work pretty well. Note that return value is text from `(.*?)`. If you want to get tag name you may use `(...)` wrap `ddf2k12`. Then the combination version with your `img` tag would be like this.

```
\[(ddf2k12|img):[a-zA-Z0-9]+\](.*?)\[/(ddf2k12|img):[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]
```

Comment: Should there be a `(?s)` there for the dot to also match newlines? this might be a good place to use a multiline match with `(?x)` so that you can include comments. I’m a little bothered to see things repeated in the regex: both `(ddf2k12|img)` and `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` occur twice, which risks getting out of sync because you’ve violated the DRY (“don’t repeat yourself”) rule.  I think you should be able to use named groups here to make this more self-documenting, and more maintainable from a code-safety point of view.